# Python Pyramid PServe refuses to serve

Tags: python, pyramid

I notice strange behavior with my Python - Pyramid setup. I have done this method thousands of time before without any problem, but today it refuses to work with me. The command that I've been using is:

```
pserve development.ini --reload
```

Previously I was able to modify the code or the template files, and see the changes immediately. Now when I make some changes to the code, even the template files, the changes won't reflected after I hit the browser refresh. Even after I restarted pserve, the page will still retain the old code. Out of desperation, I call in my project file:

```
python setup.py install
```

This time, I can see my changes, but I didn't have to go through this hassle before. As far as I remember, I did not make any changes to the project file. Maybe someone else did, does anyone know what is wrong with the setup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`python setup.py install` is a one-off installation, copying your source into the site-packages. What you'd prefer to do is have `pserve` look at the source in your development directory, which is done by only "linking" the source to the site-packages via `python setup.py develop` (which you should only need to run when you change your `setup.py` file.